# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown in c# (while retrieving the data form the database getting this error )

Tags: c#

I saw so many example on this error but I didn't get the relevant answer

This is how I written the logic to avoid this kind of error but it is not working (I'm not sure this is the correct way to do)

Calling or fetching the limited rows:

```
        public DataSet maa_5min_eq_his(int sno, long maxLimit)
        {
            try
            {
                //MemoryCache memCache = MemoryCache.Default;

                //if (memCache.Get("CacheData") != null)
                //{
                //    DataSet ds = (DataSet)memCache.Get("CacheData");
                //    return ds;
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //aasmaaCon.Open();
                //SELECT * FROM maa_5min_eq_his
                //SELECT * FROM maa_5min_eq_his LIMIT 8000000
                //SELECT * FROM maa_5min_eq_his WHERE a_symbol = 'ADANIENTEQ' OR a_symbol= 'ASHOKLEYEQ';
                //MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM maa_5min_eq_his WHERE SNO>0 LIMIT 8000000", aasmaaCon);//8000000
                MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM maa_5min_eq_his WHERE SNO>" + sno + " LIMIT " + maxLimit + "", aasmaaCon);//8000000
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                //aasmaaCon.Close();
                //memCache.Add("CacheData", ds, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15));
                return ds;
                //}
            }
            catch
            {
                aasmaaCon.Close();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

In the code page I written this logic (to fetch the bulk of row's step by step) :

```
                System.Data.DataSet findata = new System.Data.DataSet();
                System.Data.DataSet symbolltp = mAE_Repo.maa_5min_eq_his(0, 8000000);
                Thread.Sleep(150000);
                int nData = Convert.ToInt32(symbolltp.Tables[0].Rows[symbolltp.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1]["SNO"]);

                System.Data.DataSet rtp = mAE_Repo.maa_5min_eq_his(nData, 8000000);

                Thread.Sleep(50000);
                int fData = Convert.ToInt32(rtp.Tables[0].Rows[symbolltp.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1]["SNO"]);

                System.Data.DataSet ftp = mAE_Repo.maa_5min_eq_his(fData, 8000000);
```

But still I'm getting the same error:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown in c#

Note: In my database total I have 25 million rows

I followed this kind of `app.config` code also

```
    <runtime>
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
```

I didn't get the proper result from those

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this kind of issues without fail.

Comment: can I check: "crore"=10 million, so we're talking about 25 million rows - is that right? I mean... yes, that's quite a lot of data - it will hurt to load that into memory; do you really need to? normally, we leave the data in the database; it is happy, warm, and cosy there

Comment: Don't load as much data in one go. Add more memory to your system.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with 25M records in memory, or how big each of these records is, but you should probably consider 1) selecting only the fields you actually require and 2) chunking the data into manageable pieces of, let's say 10k rows at a time.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure I want that 25 million rows to load into my DataSet (Means : that data for calculation purpose )

How can I get all the records without fail ?

Comment: Er.. Get the DB to do the calc?

Comment: Wait.. Did you just say you want to load 25 million rows.. into a *DataTable*? Ho ho ho..

Comment: You might want to do your aggregate / transformation operations on the database side. Let's assume your row size is only 1KB. That means 25 million rows occupy 25 thousand megabytes or 25 gigabytes of RAM at the very least. Do you have 25 GB free ram on your machine?